# Reading and writing to an xml file with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing

I am rather new to the programming world ( I'm a network guy ). I have however been asked to develop a front end that configures an xml file for a console application. The console application reads from this xml file and opens multiple instances of a browser, one instance per monitor (6 monitors in total). There are 4 control centers, each of which has 6 monitors. Each control center is run off a seperate pc. These pc's are not on the network and do not have access to each other. I have been told I can also not use a database.

Each monitor will display one website at a time, there could be multiple sites listed to be displayed on the specific monitor so they will periodically change. Each control center will show different sites.

My first question: Is this XML valid?

```
<ControlCenter>
  <Monitor>
      <monitor_id>0</monitor_id>
      <browser_short_na>ie</browser_short_na>
  <url_list>
    <url>
    <url_id>0</url_id>
    <url_na><![CDATA[http://www.hmv.com]]></url_na>
         <parameter><![CDATA[]]></parameter>
    </url>
    <url>
    <url_id>1</url_id>
    <url_na><![CDATA[http://www.amazon.com]]></url_na>
         <parameter><![CDATA[]]></parameter>
    </url>
    <url>
    <url_id>2</url_id>
    <url_na><![CDATA[http://www.google.com]]></url_na>
         <parameter><![CDATA[]]></parameter>
    </url>
 </url_list>
   </Monitor>
   <Monitor>
   <monitor_id>1</monitor_id>
   <browser_short_na>ie</browser_short_na>
    <url_list>
    <url>
            <url_id>0</url_id>
            <url_na><![CDATA[http://www.amazon.com]]></url_na>
            <parameter><![CDATA[]]></parameter>
    </url>
    </url_list>
   </Monitor>
</ControlCenter>
```

What I do so far is open the xml file and add all the monitors to a combobox

```
 Dim dom As New Xml.XmlDocument
    dom.Load("test.xml")
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim monitorid As String = String.Empty
    For Each node As Xml.XmlNode In  dom.SelectNodes("//ControlCenter/Monitor/monitor_id")
        monitorid = node.InnerText
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(monitorid)
    Next
```

This is now where I am stuck. Once the users selects one of the monitors from the combobox I then need to get all the information for that monitor. So I need the browser_short_na, and all the urls all based on the monitor_id selected.

I have tried creating a dataset, loading the xmlfile using readxml. I then tried creating a dataview pointing to that dataset. Tried adding a RowFilter to the dataview.

```
Dim val As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString

    Dim dsXmlFile As New DataSet
    dsXmlFile.ReadXml("test.xml")

Dim dv As New DataView
    dv.Table = dsXmlFile.Tables(0)

    Dim drv As DataRowView
    dv.RowFilter = "monitor_id = " & val

Dim url As String = ""
    'Retrieve my values returned in the result
    For Each drv In dv
        url = drv("url_na")
    Next
```

When I step through the code and look at the for each loop it fails with the message "url_na is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Monitor."

I am thinking I am not handling the url_list section correctly.

Once all the information for the selected monitor is read I will display the values in textboxes/listboxes which the users can then edit. If they then save it should write the new values to the xml file. They could also choose to add additional urls to the list, or even create an entirely new monitor section.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go the other way around for your issue:

1. Define a Class (or several classes) that will hold the data you need.
2. Use a simple serializer to load/save from/to that file.

If you do so, then your issue with the selection is just a classical WPF issue.

```
Public Class Monitor
    Public Property MonitorId As integer
    Public Property ListOfUrl As List(Of String)
End Class
```

`MonitorsConfiguration` will then reference a `List(Of Monitor)` object.

You can use a `ViewModel` object to handle a `MonitorsConfiguration` easily.
This `ViewModel` has a `SelectedMonitorIndex` property, and updates a `UrlForThisMonitor` List of url when the index property changes.
(Obviously it should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

Ok so a little view on what the ViewModel might look like :

```
Public Class MonitorsConfigurationVM
       Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

   ' creates a new VM. Throws exception if file name is not valid 
   Public Sub New(ConfigFileName As String)
      _FileName = ConfigFileName
      _MonitorsConfiguration = // Deserialization of the file //
      _MonitorIndex = 0 
   End Sub

  Public Property MonitorIndex As integer
   Get
     return _MonitorIndex
   End Get
   Set (Value)
     if (_MonitorIndex = value) then return
     ' you might want to perform check here and allow only valid index
     _MonitorIndex = value
     _UrlIndex=0
     NotifyPropertyChanged("MonitorIndex")
     NotifyPropertyChanged("MonitorUrls")
     NotifyPropertyChanged("HasUrl")
     NotifyPropertyChanged("UrlIndex")
   End Set
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property HasUrl As Boolean  
   Get
      return Not (MonitorUrls Is Nothing OrElse MonitorUrls.count = 0 )
      ' ( might be used to disable the listbox bound to MonitorUrl )
   End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property MonitorUrls As List(Of String)
  Get
    return _MonitorConfiguration(_MonitorIndex).ListOfUrl  '(you might want to chk)
  End Get
  End Property

  Public Property UrlIndex As Integer 
  Get
     return _UrlIndex
  End Get
  Set (value)
    if value = _UrlIndex then return
    ' you might want to perform some check here
    _UrlIndex = value
    NotifyPropertyChanged("UrlIndex")
  End Set
  End Property

 ' And Also : AddMonitor  /   AddUrl  /  SaveConfiguration / ...

  Private _FileName As String = Nothing
  Private _MonitorsConfiguration As List(Of Monitor)=Nothing
  Private _MonitorIndex As integer = 0

   Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
       RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
   End Sub

   Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

End Class
```

Comment: Hate to be one of those guys, but could you give me a code example of how I would create the ViewModel object?

Comment: not sure if you are updated of edits : i edited my post btw :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPath for parsing the XML Document.

- Load the xml file in XMLDocument
- Create a XMLNodeList and use XPath to select nodes from loaded xml
  document.
- Then parse the nodes list and extract all info for selected monitor
  node based on id.

Here are XPath expression helpful to you:

1. For selecting monitor nodes from file: "**/ControlCenter/Monitor**"
2. For selecting browser_na field based on monitor id:  "**/ControlCenter/Monitor[monitor_id='0']/browser_short_na**"
3. For selection urls based on monitor id: "**/ControlCenter/Monitor[monitor_id='0']/url_list/url/url_na**"

Hope it works for you.